# I want to display custom fields in Woocommerce Bookings Availibility

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce Booking and Woocommerce Bookings Availibility to show my booking availibility as a schedule. Here's how it looks like right now:

[image]

However I would like to add custom fields information inside of each blocks like "Boat type", "Destination", etc. How do I proceed with this?

This is the goal I would like to achieve:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. I have been stuck in this for forever.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options using which you can attempt to achieve this but this might need some development-level knowledge as there is no option to configure this from the admin dashboard. Hope these options will benefit you.

WooCommerce provides detailed documentation for its major plugins so it has developer documentation for WooCommerce Bookings plugin but I can't find the same for Bookings Availability.

**1. Bookings Templates**

You can modify the display template of the bookings screen using this. Please check more details here: https://woocommerce.com/document/bookings-templates/

**2. Hooks**

There are filters that are introduced before processing the fetched data(to insert some extra data/modify the entered data) as well as before sending the data to the front end for display. You can look for the appropriate filter in your case that accepts the data(with some extra fields) and display all of them on the screen.

Hooks details here: https://woocommerce.com/document/bookings-action-and-filter-reference/